# Rails app rendered white blank page! Unicorn + Nginx + mina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rvm, unicorn, mina

I have spent whole of the day to solve this issue, but I didn't get it yet.
I created a droplet in digitaloceon, I installed rvm and deployed my rails application with mina. I have created swap area.

So, I'm sure about my app path is correct in nginx configuration and in routes.rb. But rails rendered a blank white page on my domain name and server IP as well.

I checked unicorn.stder.log I saw these logs:

```
Instance method "open" is already defined in Object, use generic helper instead or set StateMachine::Machine.ignore_method_conflicts = true. 
I, [2015-04-21T14:35:55.148457 #18765]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/tmp/unicorn.sock fd=12
I, [2015-04-21T14:35:55.169044 #18765]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2015-04-21T14:35:55.186923 #18769]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2015-04-21T14:35:55.195608 #18772]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
E, [2015-04-21T14:35:58.821812 #18769] ERROR -- : app error: (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 8 column 56 (Psych::SyntaxError)
E, [2015-04-21T14:35:58.821983 #18769] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse'
E, [2015-04-21T14:35:58.822057 #18769] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
E, [2015-04-21T14:35:58.822106 #18769] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
E, [2015-04-21T14:35:58.822141 #18769] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
E, [2015-04-21T14:35:58.822174 #18769] ERROR -- : /var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `secrets'
E, [2015-04-21T14:35:58.822216 #18769] ERROR -- : /var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application.rb:477:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
E, [2015-04-21T14:35:58.822251 #18769] ERROR -- : /var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application.rb:195:in `env_config'
E, [2015-04-21T14:35:58.822301 #18769] ERROR -- : /var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
```

So here is my nginx *sites-available/myapp.com*

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {


    listen 80;
    server_name .mydomain.com;

    # Application root, as defined previously
    root /var/www/myapp/current/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
    }
```

Can anybody tell me, what is wrong? Please!

Comment: 1) what is the domain name you are typing in the browser that makes you get the blank page?

2) is your rails app running? If so in which port?

Comment: it works on default port (22). You can check it on mercandiamond.com. The app doesn't work properly when I refresh it I get the error below in unicorn.log

Answer (score 0):

See if this revised nginx config works

```
upstream app {
  # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {


  listen 80;
  server_name mercandiamond.com www.mercandiamond.com;

  # Application root, as defined previously
  root /var/www/myapp/current/public;

  location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:22/;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
}
```

If it doesn't, make sure that

1) sites-enabled/myapp.com matches sites-available/myapp.com

2) run nginx -s reload

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sites-enabled/myapp.com and sites-avilable/myapp are the same. I think the problem is harder.

Comment: did you revise your nginx config? Regardless of anything, your server_name and proxy_pass you originally listed should be fixed.

Comment: I got "No data received" instead of blank page in chrome browser.

Comment: well at least no blank page anymore :-)

Assuming you didn't change nginx default configuration on /etc/nginx/nginx.conf , Check nginx error log at /var/log/nginx/error.log and see what error it is giving.